# If $f$ is Schwartz and harmonic, then $\nabla f=0$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ a Schwartz function over $\mathbb R^n$ (it decay very fast at infinity), and harmonic. I find that such function are such that $\nabla f=0$, but I'm sure it's wrong. So what's wrong in my argument :

Using divergence theorem, $$0=-\int_{\mathbb R^n\backslash B(x,\varepsilon)}f\Delta f=\int_{\mathbb R^n\backslash B(x,\varepsilon)}|\nabla f|^2-\int_{\partial B(x,\varepsilon)}f\nabla f\cdot \nu,$$
and thus $$\int_{\mathbb R^n\backslash B(x,\varepsilon)}|\nabla f|^2=\int_{\partial B(x,\varepsilon)}f\nabla f\cdot \nu.$$
Using dominated convergence theorem I finally get 
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n}|\nabla f|^2=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{\partial B(x,\varepsilon)}f\nabla f\cdot \nu=0,$$
and thus $|\nabla f|=0$. Therefore $\nabla f=0$.

What's wrong here ?

Comment: A bounded entire harmonic function is constant (Liouville).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is wrong.

By Liouville's theorem a bounded entire harmonic function is constant. Since Schwartz functions tend to $0$ for $\lVert x\rVert \to +\infty$, it follows that $0$ is the only harmonic Schwartz function.